# How to set ctag in vim editor one time

Tags: linux, vim, ctags

I have created ctags for my project. Now every time, I open file in vim editor I set ctag location. Is it possible to set the ctag location for one time in some where that I don't know, So that when I open a file from my project in vim, it will start working, I do not need to fire this command `set tags=~/tags`.
Please help.

Comment: Just add that command to your `~/.vimrc`? Alternatively, consider storing the `tags` file in the directory where your project lives, that way the default of `./tags` will work when you work from the project's top directory...

Comment: if I open ~/.vimrc . It is opening a new file. I have .vim in my home directory. Where does ~/.vimrc belongs to?

Comment: Try `:e $MYVIMRC` from inside Vim, that will work if you already have a vimrc somewhere... But `~/.vimrc` (outside `.vim`) is correct, it's the correct file. Try to add that command there, see if it works.

Comment: You can also use `~/.vim/vimrc` (recommended if your vim supports it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `:echo $MYVIMRC` within Vim to print the location of your `.vimrc` file. If the variable is not set, you'll want to create the file yourself. Typically its location is `~/.vimrc`, but as the comments mention there are other [supported locations](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#system-vimrc). Once you've created the file, you can just add the command as you normally would: `set tags=~/tags`. As other comments mentioned, it's probably for the best to put your `tags` file in some constant, relative-to-the-project-root-folder place. I personally follow [Tim Pope's ctags guide](https://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html) for all my Git projects.

I mean, which would you rather have,

```
set tags=./tags
```

or

```
set tags=/some/project/tags,/some/other/project/tags,/yet/another/project/tags,...
```